# код,работающий в шаблоне MahApps.Metro.Application не работает в стандартном WpfApplication

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть поле,которое должно сообщать юзеру о необходимости получения строки.Приложение использует шаблон MahApps.Metro.Application и эта функция реализуется с помощью `TextBoxHelper``а, а именно его свойства `HasText`.В разметке это выглядит примерно так:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource BodyTextBlockText}"/>
    <TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.HasText="{Binding IsBodyEmpty,Mode=TwoWay}"
             AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding Body}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource EmptyFieldMessage }"
               Foreground="Red" FontSize="14"
               Visibility="{Binding IsBodyEmpty,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

В застраничном коде определено свойство `IsBodyEmpty`:

```
public bool IsBodyEmpty
{
    get { return !isBodyEmpty; }
    set
    {
        if (isBodyEmpty != value)
        {
            isBodyEmpty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Тот же код в комбинации с той же разметкой отказывается работать в стандартном `WpfApplication`.Пакет MahApps установлен.Приложение настроено по [Quick Start`y](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html).   Как решить проблему?

Comment: Так а что именно-то не работает? Симптомы какие?

Comment: @andreycha,симптомы проявляются в том что,TextBlock с подсказкой не убирается после начала ввода в поле в шаблоне WpfApplication,но все работает в MahApps.Metro.Application.

Comment: @andreycha,разница между приложениями только в том,что при создании первого был выбран шаблон MahApps.Metro.Application, а при создании второго-стандартный встроенный WpfApplication

Comment: А точно ничего не менялось? Геттер в свойстве `IsBodyEmpty` выглядит подозрительно -- почему там отрицание?

Comment: @andreycha,текстблок  должен появлятся,когда поле пустое(HasText==false),и пропадать,когда HasText==true.Так,как в коде используются биндинги,то свойство IsBodyEmpty должно быть равно true, в  то время,когда  HasText равно false.Поэтому и отрицание в геттере.